MVC c# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Boa Noite,
Estou com um problema no meu código.
Neste momento já tenho os post a funcionar. Quando um user entra nos detalhes do Post para poder responder, eu carrego no Botao de Submit e dá este erro :
Botao de Submit

Erro : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Areas_Customer_Views_Posts_Details.ExecuteAsync() in Details.cshtml


Aqui vai o meu controller e a minha view do Details.
using Hayashi.DataAccess.Data;
using Hayashi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace HayashiGreenStoreWeb.Areas
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PostsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Posts
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? pageNumber)
        {
            var applicationDbContext = _context.Posts.Include(q => q.User).Include(a => a.Answers);
            int pageSize = 3;

            return View(await PaginatedList<Post>.CreateAsync(applicationDbContext.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }


        // GET: Posts/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Posts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Posts
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .Include(c => c.Answers)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Create
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {

            return View("Create");
        }

        // POST: Posts/Create
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Description,IdentityUserId")] Post Post)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(Post);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(Post);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddAnswer([Bind("Id,Content, PostId, IdentityUserId")] Answer answer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(answer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            var post = await _context.Posts
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .Include(a => a.Answers)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.Id == answer.PostId);

            return View("Details", post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Edit/5
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Posts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var Post = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(id);

            if (Post.IdentityUserId != User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", Post.IdentityUserId);
            return View(Post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Edit/5
       
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,Description,IdentityUserId")] Post Post)
        {
            if (id != Post.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(Post);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PostExists(Post.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", Post.IdentityUserId);
            return View(Post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Delete/5
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Posts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var Post = await _context.Posts
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (Post.IdentityUserId != User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return View(Post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Posts == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Posts'  is null.");
            }
            var Post = await _context.Posts.FindAsync(id);
            if (Post != null)
            {
                _context.Posts.Remove(Post);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool PostExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Posts?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }

}

@model Hayashi.Models.Post
@using Hayashi.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h3>@Model.Title</h3> 
<p>@Model.Description</p>
<p>- @Model.User.UserName</p>

<h4>All Answers:</h4>
@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
{
    <p>@answer.Content - @answer.User.UserName</p>
    <hr />
}


<form asp-action="AddAnswer" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="IdentityUserId" class="form-control" value="@UserManager.GetUserId(User)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</form>

<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>

Espero que possam Ajudar, Estou há horas neste problema.

já fez debug para ver o que está vazio (null) ?

Esse erro é relacionado com a inicialização do objeto.
